# SwiftUI - Sheet not showing navigation title

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am using sheets deep within the app and app does display navigation title on all the sheets. But for some reason I am not seeing navigation title on the sheet which appears from the first view of the app. Am not able to figure out why that's happening.

Is there anything that I am doing wrong?

This is how the code in my app is... ContentView is wrapped in NavigationStack. Content View opens another view (FirstView) as navigation destination and this view presents a sheet which is where I am expecting to show the navigation title and a bottom bar. I haven't started working on bottom bar yet, but am unsure of why nav title isn't showing.

***Code:***

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showDetails = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                Button("First View") {
                    showDetails = true
                }
            }
            .navigationDestination(isPresented: $showDetails) {
                FirstView()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct FirstView: View {
    @State private var showDetails = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Show Sheet") {
                showDetails = true
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showDetails) {
            SheetView()
        }
    }
}

struct SheetView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(getAttributedText()).font(.body)
            Spacer()
        }
        // .navigationTitle("Settings") // This doesn't work nor does toolbaritem.
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                Text("Settings").foregroundStyle(Color.black)
            }
        }
        .interactiveDismissDisabled()
    }
    
    func getAttributedText() -> AttributedString {
        var attributedString = AttributedString("")
        
        var disclaimerText = AttributedString("This is an attributed text with links and underlined text. Some more text just for this sample app.")
        disclaimerText.foregroundColor = .black
        attributedString.append(disclaimerText)


        return attributedString
    }
}
```

Comment: `SheetView` is not in a `NavigationStack` or anything like that. Why do you expect to see a navigation bar?

Comment: Ah.. I see what you are saying. My understanding was that since I am presenting it from a view that is presented as Navigation Destination (FirstView), then the sheet should also have a nav bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigation destinations get a navigation bar because they are in the same navigation stack as the root view of the `NavigationStack`. Presenting a sheet does not put the presented view into the stack, so sheets do not get a navigation bar just because it is presented by a view in a navigation stack.

You need a separate `NavigationStack` to show a navigation bar on the presented sheet view.

```
// in .sheet(isPresented: $showDetails) {
NavigationStack {
    SheetView()
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I ended up doing. Thanks for correcting my understanding about navigation stacks!